# Form Load not working after Application.Run method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to perform a function after `Application.Run` in main method. I have added code for Form_Load but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var frm1 = new LoginM();
        frm1.Load += LoginFormLoad;
        Application.Run(frm1);
    }

    private static void LoginFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginM test = new LoginM();
        test.LoginExistingusers();

    }
    public void LoginExistingusers()
    {
        mtxtPassword.Text = "Form has loaded";
        MbtnLogin.Click += new System.EventHandler(MbtnLogin_Click);
    }
```

Comment: please use the designer to add event handlers, then you'll avoid issues like these

Comment: Im unable to use designer because the form is designed by third party controls called material Skin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Form.Load Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=netframework-4.8):

Also you should use sender parameter instead of creating new instance of `LoginM`

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    var frm1 = new LoginM();
    frm1.Load += LoginFormLoad;
    Application.Run(frm1);

}

static void LoginFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as LoginM).LoginExistingusers();
}
```

Comment: In the LoginFormLoad method, I'm trying to click login button. So, the application has to be run first before calling the load method. I hope you understood the problem. Please see if you are able to find any solution

Comment: Do you have `Button_Click` in your LoginM form?

Comment: private static void LoginFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoginM test = new LoginM();
            test.LoginExistingusers();
            
        }        public void LoginExistingusers()
        {
            mtxtPassword.Text = "Form has loaded";
            MbtnLogin.Click += new System.EventHandler(MbtnLogin_Click);
        }

Comment: Updated answer. `(sender as LoginM).LoginExistingusers();` please check.

Comment: its not clicking the login button, is this line correct? MbtnLogin.Click += new System.EventHandler(MbtnLogin_Click); There's a method for MbtnLogin_Click

Comment: Did you try to just call `MbtnLogin_Click()`?

Comment: Pass it null `MbtnLogin_Click(null, null)`?